# After print a global variable, append it to a global list in the for loop. Why the value in each for loop and in the list are not same?

Tags: python

```
transactions_clean = \
['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '09/15/17', 'Herbert Tran', 
'$7.29', 'white&blue', 
'09/15/17', 'Paul Clarke', '$12.52', 'white&blue', '09/15/17', 'Lucille 
Caldwell', '$5.13', 
'white', '09/15/17', 'Eduardo George', '$20.39', 'white&yellow', 
'09/15/17', 'Danny Mclaughlin', 
'$30.82', 'purple', '09/15/17', 'Stacy Vargas', '$1.85', 
'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Shaun Brock', 
'$17.98', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Erick Harper', '$17.41', 
'blue', '09/15/17', 'Michelle Howell', 
'$28.59', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'Carroll Boyd', '$14.51', 'purple&blue', 
'09/15/17', 'Teresa Carter', '$19.64', 
'white', '09/15/17', 'Jacob Kennedy', '$11.40', 'white&red', 
'09/15/17', 
'Craig Chambers', '$8.79', 'white&blue&red', 
'09/15/17', 'Peggy Bell', '$8.65', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'Kenneth 
Cunningham', '$10.53', 'green&blue', '09/15/17', 
'Marvin Morgan', '$16.49', 'green&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'Marjorie 
Russell', '$6.55', 'green&blue&red', '09/15/17', 
'Israel Cummings', '$11.86', 'black', '09/15/17', 'June Doyle', 
'$22.29', 'black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Jaime Buchanan', 
'$8.35', 'white&black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Rhonda Farmer', '$2.91', 
'white&black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'Darren Mckenzie', 
'$22.94', 'green', '09/15/17', 'Rufus Malone', '$4.70', 'green&yellow', 
'09/15/17', 'Hubert Miles', '$3.59', 
'green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17']


thread_sold = []
temp_thread = [[], []]
thread_sold1 =[]
for i in range(len(transactions_clean)):
  if i % 4 == 2:
    temp_thread[0] = transactions_clean[i]
    thread_sold1.append(transactions_clean[i])
  if i % 4 == 3:
    temp_thread[1] = transactions_clean[i]
    thread_sold1.append(transactions_clean[i])
    print(temp_thread)
    thread_sold.append(temp_thread)

print(thread_sold)
print(thread_sold1)
```

In (if i % 4 == 3:) part, after I print temp_thread, I append temp_thread to the thread_sold list. Intuitively, the value of temp_thread in this two statements are supposed to be the same.

When I print temp_thread in (if i % 4 == 3:) part, it generates the right output, which changes during the iteration. However, when I print thread_sold, which should be a list of all temp_thread, all elements become the same thing. All the elements in the thread_sold list become [‘green&yellow&blue’, ‘09/15/17’].

Can anybody tell me why?

```
output:
['white', '09/15/17']
['white&blue', '09/15/17']
['white&blue', '09/15/17']
['white', '09/15/17']
['white&yellow', '09/15/17']
['purple', '09/15/17']
['purple&yellow', '09/15/17']
['purple&yellow', '09/15/17']
['blue', '09/15/17']
['blue', '09/15/17']
['purple&blue', '09/15/17']
['white', '09/15/17']
['white&red', '09/15/17']
['white&blue&red', '09/15/17']
['blue', '09/15/17']
['green&blue', '09/15/17']
['green&blue&red', '09/15/17']
['green&blue&red', '09/15/17']
['black', '09/15/17']
['black&yellow', '09/15/17']
['white&black&yellow', '09/15/17']
['white&black&yellow', '09/15/17']
['green', '09/15/17']
['green&yellow', '09/15/17']
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17']
[['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], ['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17'], 
['green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17']]
['white', '09/15/17', 'white&blue', '09/15/17', 'white&blue', 
'09/15/17', 'white', '09/15/17', 'white&yellow', '09/15/17', 'purple', 
'09/15/17', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17', 
'blue', '09/15/17', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'purple&blue', '09/15/17', 
'white', '09/15/17', 'white&red', '09/15/17', 'white&blue&red', 
'09/15/17', 'blue', '09/15/17', 'green&blue', '09/15/17', 
'green&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'green&blue&red', '09/15/17', 'black', 
'09/15/17', 'black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'white&black&yellow', 
'09/15/17', 'white&black&yellow', '09/15/17', 'green', '09/15/17', 
'green&yellow', '09/15/17', 'green&yellow&blue', '09/15/17']
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are mutable, so every time you're doing this: temp_thread[0] or temp_thread[1], you're always changing the values of the same List. As they are mutable, when you're doing thread_sold.append(temp_thread), you're just adding a new pointer to that list, which with every iteration is getting its values changed to the most recently evaluated.

To solve this really easily, you can change

```
    if i % 4 == 3:
      temp_thread[1] = transactions_clean[i]
      thread_sold1.append(transactions_clean[i])
      print(temp_thread)
      thread_sold.append(temp_thread)
```

for

```
    if i % 4 == 3:
      temp_thread[1] = transactions_clean[i]
      thread_sold1.append(transactions_clean[i])
      print(temp_thread)
      t = tuple(temp_thread)
      thread_sold.append(t)
```

Using a tuple, because it's not a mutable object, will avoid the problem of updating the value.

Comment: The answer really helps me!!! Thanks very much, it wastes me 4 hours to figure out this problem. The most important thing is that you point out the key point is adding a pointer to the list.

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on the other answer of this post because I'm a new user, but you should notice that the other answer doesn't give you back the format that you wanted. I guess you wanted a list of lists, because you want to be able to iterate through every single list inside that list, So obtain the first element of the big list, and then see the color or the date by doing L[1][1], but with the previous answer, you're just adding everything in one list, whereas by using the tuples, you can still iterate.

Answer (score 0):

It is the age old problem of pointers. Your code repeatedly adds a pointer to temp_thread and thus all the entries reflect the most recent value. I have added two lines that will correctly append the values (currently commented out).

```
thread_sold = []
temp_thread = [[], []]
thread_sold1 =[]
for i in range(len(transactions_clean)):
    if i % 4 == 2:
        temp_thread[0] = transactions_clean[i]
        thread_sold1.append(transactions_clean[i])
        print('Clean', i, transactions_clean[i])
    if i % 4 == 3:
        temp_thread[1] = transactions_clean[i]
        thread_sold1.append(transactions_clean[i])
        print('Temp Thread', temp_thread)
        thread_sold.append(temp_thread) #Remove this line
        #thread_sold.append(temp_thread[0])
        #thread_sold.append(temp_thread[1])

temp_thread[0] = 'Well'
temp_thread[1] = 'Now'
print('First Thread')
print(thread_sold)
print('Second Thread')
print(thread_sold1)
```